# Graphite function to get "today so far" incremental count?

Tags: graphite, grafana, gauge

I have a counter and would like to display a `singlestat` on grafana for today's incremental, something like `Current MAX(gauge) - MIN(guage)`, since the gauge is monotone increasing, it also equals to `Current(gauge) - MIDNIGHT(gauge)

Which function should I use in graphite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [summarize()](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize) function - or [smartSummarize()](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.smartSummarize), if you have it.
Something like

```
summarize(nonNegativeDerivative(your counter), '1d', 'sum', false)
```